# How do I put a WinJS.UI.Menu inside of a win-splitview-content section?

Tags: javascript, windows-10, winjs, windows-10-universal

I have a very simple app. I started with the WinJS App (Universal Windows) template in VS2015. I have a split view and inside the split view content section I have a menu. The menu appears when the control button is clicked but none of the options are selectable.

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitView" data-win-options="{closedDisplayMode: 'overlay',panePlacement:'left'}">
    <div class="win-splitview-pane">
    </div>
    <div class="win-splitview-content">
        <button id="selectionButton">Selection</button>
        <div id="selectionMenu" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Menu">
            <button data-win-options="{label:'Forward',type:'toggle'}" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.MenuCommand"></button>
            <button data-win-options="{label:'Reply',type:'toggle'}" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.MenuCommand"></button>
            <button data-win-options="{label:'Reply All',type:'toggle'}" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.MenuCommand"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript code for this is simple (`initSelection` is called in the `app.onactivated` section):

```
function initSelection() {
    document.getElementById("selectionButton").addEventListener("click", showFlyout, false);
}
function showFlyout() {
    document.getElementById("selectionMenu").winControl.show(document.getElementById("selectionButton"), "bottom", "left");
}
```

Is this even possible? How? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to put the selection menu outside of the split view content section like this:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitView" data-win-options="{closedDisplayMode: 'overlay',panePlacement:'left'}">
    <div class="win-splitview-pane">
    </div>
    <div class="win-splitview-content">
        <button id="selectionButton">Selection</button>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="win-interactive" id="selectionMenu" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Menu">
    <button class="win-interactive" data-win-options="{label:'Forward'}" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.MenuCommand"></button>
    <button class="win-interactive" data-win-options="{label:'Reply'}" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.MenuCommand"></button>
    <button class="win-interactive" data-win-options="{label:'Reply All'}" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.MenuCommand"></button>
</div>
```

This is the recommendation from the WinJS team: https://github.com/winjs/winjs/issues/1553#issuecomment-159416488

Once you do this it'll work.